# Lenovo Rapid Charge - is it safe for my battery?

Tags: battery, lenovo-laptop, battery-life

I'v bought my new laptop 2 weeks ago. After downloading Lenovo Vantage I have noticed function "Rapid Charge".

I just wanna know is it safe and not damaging for my laptop accumulator and not cause premature dying of battery or anything that.

[image]

Comment: Usually, if a manufacturer gives you a quick charge option, it is because it is safe to use. But safe for long-term: all quick charge solutions are possibly damaging for lithium cells.